# XML format error (backspace code 8 in ascii)

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to read a XML but its returning wrong format. The XML structure is right, but in one of the values I have an backscape (code 8 in ascii) example:

```
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test versao="1.0"><is_apply>0</is_apply><result>some value in xml (heres goes the backspace value) will be wrong</result></test>'

try:
    doc = parseString(xml)
except Exception, e:
    raise XMLErrorUtils(e, u'Falha ao realizar o parse do xml.')
```

Any solution?

Comment: Not enough information. What is "pass XML"? Are you creating the XML or reading an existing XML file? Show the code you are using and indicate the error and where it occurs.

Comment: Sorry, im creating xml and after I need to read it...

Comment: I edited with the question, look the code

Answer (score 2):

ASCII 8 is not a valid character in XML.  [Here's the relevant section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-text).

If you want that character in XML you should use [a character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref) - `&#8;`

Comment: Yeah, isnt a valid character XML, maybe should I replace to a valid, right?

Comment: Replace it with `&#8;` - that is the equivalent.

Comment: you know what is the expression used in W3C document? like this `ETag    ::=    '</' Name S? '>'`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to use &#8; !!

I have tried to open these xml files with Firefox and Notepad++. Both are synchronous in claiming &#8; is invalid but neither has a problem to open/parse &#9;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contact>&#8;</contact>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contact>&#9;</contact>
```

Output:

```
XML Parsing Error: reference to invalid character number
Location: file:///charcode8.xml Line Number 2, Column 10
```